# Why is my CSS transform: translate effecting multiple elements?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 buttons that have separate 'active' pseudo classes and for some reason when I click on either one it performs the translate on both.

It's only in codepen whilst I'm experimenting but I'm wondering if there's something really obvious I'm missing/forgetting?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.btn {
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  padding: 11px 20px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 2px 1px;
  border-color: #333333;
}

.primary {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.primary:hover {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.primary:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 1px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 1px);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 1px 1px 1px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.secondary {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.secondary:hover {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

.secondary:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 1px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 1px);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 1px 1px 1px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
  <a href="#" class="btn primary">PRIMARY</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn secondary">SECONDARY</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the alignment default for `inline-block` is `baseline`. Just change it to `top`.

```
.btn {
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  padding: 11px 20px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* add this */
  height: 38px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 2px 1px;
  border-color: #333333;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6sq9ogth/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving them separate ID values?  For instance, you could do this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" id="primary">PRIMARY</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="secondary">SECONDARY</a>
```

and change your css to

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.btn {
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  padding: 11px 20px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 2px 1px;
  border-color: #333333;
}

#primary {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#primary:hover {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#primary:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 1px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 1px);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 1px 1px 1px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#secondary {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#secondary:hover {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

#secondary:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 1px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 1px);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 1px 1px 1px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like every time you click on a button it adds a 1px border to it, that's why it moves the other button down. If you remove the `display: inline-block` property from the `.btn` and instead float them left, the issue won't happen anymore, or you can add a `vertical-align: top;` property to your `.btn`.